# What is the purpose of `setLayout` method in Swing/AWT components?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

```
public void frame_pizza() {
        pizzaMenu.setVisible(true); //makes Jframe pizzaMenu visible
        pizzaMenu.setSize(1300, 750); //set size of Jframe pizzaMenu of width 1300 pixels and height 750 pixels
        pizzaMenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//exit the application when close button (X) is clicked
        p2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        pizzaMenu.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }
```

What is the purpose of these 2 lines?

```
p2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 
pizzaMenu.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: I would recommend not only using the Java Docs as your first reference for understanding anything you see in code, but also finding **better code** to try and understand in the first place. 1) The method name veers from accepted nomenclature (should be `framePizza()`) 2) The panel or frame is apparently set visible before layouts are set (the various god's knowing when the components are added) 3) `pizzaMenu.setSize(1300, 750);` is a random guess, instead call `pack()` on the top level container after all components are added. 4) .. oh, I could not be bothered going further with that. Toss it.

Comment: You are looking for Layout Managers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 3):

Java (Swing/AWT) uses something called `LayoutManager`s to place UI components on the screen. These LayoutManagers are responsible to render component such as TextField, CheckBox, etc in a predefined manner on your Window.

For example:

- A LayoutManager called `FlowLayout` simply places components one after the other.
- `BorderLayout` places components in specific sections of the window such as top(NORTH), bottom(SOUTH), left(WEST), right(EAST) and center(CENTER).
- `GridBagLayout` is another Layout Manager that gives the developer more precise rendering of components.

In your question, the `setLayout` method is setting one of these Layout Manager to manage rendering of the `pizzaMenu` frame or `p2` panel.

You should probably do learn how to use different Layout Managers in Java.

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a good place to start.

---

Hope this helps!